# DatagridView when exporting does not break line in the same cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

as you can see in the pictures:
In Datagridview I break the line, however when exporting to excel the line is broken to cell below.

I need it to break the line in the same cell

```
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
 dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

 dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
 dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
 dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
```

In the grid it is working correctly, example of the string that I am receiving:

> ```
> "Ao sol da manhã\r\n uma gota de orvalho\r\n precioso diamante."
> ```

When exporting to Excel does not break text in the "same" cell and yes to the bottom line.
[image]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    copyAlltoClipboard();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlexcel.Visible = true;
    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
   // Qubra de linha
   // xlWorkSheet.Range["B1:B500"].Cells.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].Cells.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].ColumnWidth += 15;
    //xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].AutoFit();
    xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].Cells.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].Style.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[8, 2].Style.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[9, 2].Style.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[10, 2].Style.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Columns[2].WrapText = true;
    //Set Text-Wrap for all rows true//
    xlWorkSheet.Rows.WrapText = true;
    CR.Select();
    xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);          
}
```

As you can see when breaking text to excel, it is not broken inside the same cell but rather for new rows. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Change last line of your code (PasteSpecial) and try below code.
please use Row and column variables as per your code.

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range PastToRange =
oExcel.CreateRange(row,FromCol,ToCol,ToRow,TmpWorkSheet);
PastToRange.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll,
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone,
false, false);
```